# Error in loading Map in TabActivity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-tabs

I am trying to load google map and gallery in TabListener. But I am getting the following error when I tap the map tab for the second time

```
 04-19 18:35:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(26783): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-19 18:35:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(26783): Process: hibrise.hispark2014.pixnfix, PID: 26783
04-19 18:35:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(26783): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
04-19 18:35:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(26783):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
04-19 18:35:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(26783):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
04-19 18:35:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(26783):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
04-19 18:35:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(26783):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
04-19 18:35:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(26783):    at hibrise.hispark2014.pixnfix.MapActivity.onCreateView(MapActivity.java:29)
04-19 18:35:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(26783):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
04-19 18:35:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(26783):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
04-19 18:35:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(26783):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
04-19 18:35:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(26783):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
04-19 18:35:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(26783):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
04-19 18:35:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(26783):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
04-19 18:35:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(26783):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-19 18:35:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(26783):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-19 18:35:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(26783):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-19 18:35:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(26783):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-19 18:35:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(26783):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-19 18:35:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(26783):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-19 18:35:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(26783):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-19 18:35:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(26783):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-19 18:35:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(26783):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-19 18:35:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(26783): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #7: Duplicate id 0x7f050009, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
04-19 18:35:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(26783):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4791)
04-19 18:35:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(26783):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
04-19 18:35:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(26783):    ... 19 more
```

I have coded like this

HomeActivity.Java

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity 
{
    private static final String MAP_VIEW = "MAP VIEW";
    private static final String GALLERY_VIEW = "GALLERY";
    TabHost tabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_activity);

        final ActionBar tabBar = getActionBar();
        tabBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        MapActivity map = new MapActivity();
        GaleryActivity gallery = new GaleryActivity();

        tabBar.removeAllTabs();

        tabBar.addTab(tabBar.newTab().setText(MAP_VIEW).setTabListener(new TabListener(this,map)));
        tabBar.addTab(tabBar.newTab().setText(GALLERY_VIEW).setTabListener(new TabListener(this,gallery)));

    }

    public static class TabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
        private final Fragment mFragment;
        private final FragmentActivity mActivity;

        public TabListener(FragmentActivity activity, Fragment fragment) {
            mActivity = activity;
            mFragment = fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            if (null != mFragment) {
                mActivity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, mFragment).commit();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            if (null != mFragment)
                mActivity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mFragment).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

MapActivity.java

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MapActivity extends Fragment
{
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    View rootView;
    Context context;
    double latitude = 21.0000;
    double longitude = 78.0000;
    public MapActivity(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_activity, container, false);
        context = rootView.getContext();
        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // create marker
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps ");

        // adding marker
        googleMap.addMarker(marker);
        return rootView;
    }

    /**
     * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    private void initilizeMap() 
    {
        if (googleMap == null) 
        {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(context,
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }
}
```

GalleryActivity.java

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class GaleryActivity extends Fragment
{

    public GaleryActivity(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.galery_activity, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

I am getting the error when I tap on map for the second time.

like

application opens -> gallery -> Map then app is getting crashed.

I stuck here kindly help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show your xml files..

Comment: remove `MapFragment onDestroyView()` method in your `MapActivity Fragment` this is just _PATCH_ it is not proper solution but it's worked very well if you handle things properly.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    
    <fragment 
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

</LinearLayout>

Comment: Have you solved the problem?